# DMARC for Email NOT hosted on domain but on Earthlink?

Tags: dmarc

My client has a store on Shopify (which is going to require DMARC verifications), his Domain Name is registed and Network solutions, but his domain email is hosted on Earthlink.  Shopify does not add a DMARC as far as I could find out.  I have added a DMARC to his Earthlink DNS Manager...

IS this setup going to work or cause problems?   Is there another place to add the DMARC that would be associated with this email?

TIA,
Jeff

Added a DMARC to Earthlink DNS manager.  Have not had 24 hours  to verify if it is working yet.

Comment: I guess you MUST do it at the Network Solution `DNS`. 